# Movie Script Database

Tags: data-request, film, ai

I'm looking for a database of movie scripts to use to train a [ChatterBot](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot) application.

I saw this article that mentioned that a database of movie scripts was used to train the program that generated a selection of responses.
(http://blogs.wsj.com/digits/2015/06/26/artificial-intelligence-machine-gets-testy-with-its-programmers/) It would be awesome if this was an open database somewhere.

Alternately, does anyone know if there are any similar data sets that are available that could be used. I imagine dialog scripts from plays would work equally as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try these screenplay datasets:

- http://www.imsdb.com/
- http://www.simplyscripts.com/
- http://sfy.ru/
- http://script-o-rama.com/table.shtml
- http://dailyscript.com/

But, perhaps, you may use subtitles to train only talks:

- http://opensubtitles.org/
- http://subscene.com/

Answer (score 5):

There is the [Internet Movie Script Database (IMSDb)](http://www.imsdb.com/) where you can view movie scripts online. You might be able to download enough pages to train your bot.

Alternatively, there's also [OpenSubtitles](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/opensubtitlesorg-webs-largest-completely-free-searchable-subtitles-database/), which is a collection of film subtitles that you might be able to use. These look like they're in a format meant to be used while watching a film, so you might have to convert them for your purposes.